# Applying Urysohn Lemma on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology

$A_1=\text{ Closed Unit Disk}$, $A_2=\{(1,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $A_3=\{(0,2)\}$.
Then there always exists a real-valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$f(x)=a_j$ for $x\in A_j$, $j=1,2,3$

1. Iff at least two of the numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are equal.
2. if $a_1=a_2=a_3$
3. $\forall a_i\in\mathbb{R}$
4. iff $a_1=a_2$

As all three sets are closed and we are in normal space, we can apply Urysohn's lemma to ensure the existence of such continuous function, so I see that as $A_1$ and $A_2$  are not disjoint, so $4$ is true, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Note that 2. is also true.